# epoll_wait() in a thread after close()

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I have a main thread and a worker thread. The worker thread's code looks like something like this:

```
thread = ::std::thread([this]() {
    struct epoll_event events[50];

    for (;;)
    {
      if (int const n =
        epoll_wait(efd, events, 50, -1))
      {
      //...
```

I was hoping that a `close(efd)` in the main thread would cause the worker thread's `epoll_wait()` call to return, but it doesn't happen. What can I do to exit from the worker thread's infinite loop?

Comment: You must not ever release a resource in one thread while another thread is, or might be, using it. What is your outer problem? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz +1 for 'outer problem' :-|

Comment: I thought I could use efd as a flag to signal the thread to exit. How can I exit the call to `epoll_wait()` at all, if timeout is -1? Send a signal to myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to use an explicit signal (by which I mean, signal in the ordinary sense; not necessarily a POSIX signal) from the main thread to the epoll worker thread.

The technique of using a pipe for this purpose is tried and true, but there are much better options: check out [eventfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html). To use it, you would create an eventfd file descriptor and add it to the epoll set. Signal it from the main thread by writing an 8-byte value (a value of 1 is fine).

When the worker thread sees an event on the eventfd, it knows it has been signalled and should act accordingly.

The main advantage over using a pipe is that it requires only a single file descriptor, and you don't have to worry about the possibility of blocking when you write to the pipe.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is probably as follows:

1. Have the worker thread include the read end of a pipe in the epoll set.
2. Code the worker thread to terminate if `epoll_wait` indicates the pipe is readable.
3. To terminate the worker thread, write a byte to the write end of the pipe.
4. Let the worker thread close the epoll socket, or close it after joining the worker.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem, and after doing some tests this worked for me:

I have one thread serving and waiting at epoll_wait, and one thread closing the connection.
The closing thread was something like:

```
shutdown(server_fd, SHUT_RDWR);
close(server_fd);
```

And the server thread hangs indefinitely (except if the server thread is the main thread). So I isolated the problem to experiment a bit and try to understand it better, and found that removing the close line and only shutting down the server_fd without closing it is doing the work.

Comment: It's a good trick, but works only for server sockets, not on epoll file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

So, I answer my own question after a long time. Just as I noted in my comments, it's also possible to send a signal to the thread containing the `epoll_wait()`.

```
bool terminate_meh{};

extern "C"
{

static void sig_handler(int) noexcept
{
  terminate_meh = true;
}

}

{
  struct sigaction act{};

  act.sa_handler = sig_handler;
  sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);

  sigaction(SIGUSR2, &act, {});
}
```

When you want to kill the waiting thread:

```
pthread_kill(thread.native_handle(), SIGUSR2);
```

any blocking function (`epoll_wait()`) will be interrupted and `terminate_meh` will be set.